# dynamic multidimensional array in js

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I am trying to create a multi array based on below concept , but after various tries, im hitting a roadblock. Anyone have encountered such usecase ?

Below are the scripts i used to print the value on my console.log .

```
 let tempArr = [[]];
 for(let i = 0; i < 4;i++){
    console.log(filters[i].$9)
    for(let a = 0;a < filters[i].$9.length;a++){
     console.log(filters[i].$9[a].formattedValue)
    }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

based on the logs on my inspect element, its a 2d array,
My objective is to turn this into below format , i was wondering if this is possible .

```
[   
["3/30/2021","True","True","Null] ,
["NA", "NA" , "NA" , "100001- DIRECT ASSETS (L1) "], 
["NA", "NA" , "NA" , "200001- DIRECT ASSETS (L1) "],
]
```

Example data as shown below

Example data, array consist of 20 elements, within the array, theres another object where we can extract the required details for our usecase. for this scenario , we are using $9.formattedValue
, i have only expanded the index 1 & 4 array to show how the data looks like.

This is how it looks like on the inspect elemnt of the sample data, how i get to this stage is by api calls through tableau extension.

```
(20) [Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, Q, get: ƒ, has: ƒ]
0: Q
  $1: "As Of Dtp "
  $2: "sql.text"
  $3: null
  $4: "NONE"
  $5: "dimension"
  $6: "categorical"
  $7: w {$N: bl, $K: l, $J: S, $H: R, $M: Z, …}
  $9: Array(1)
    0: {value: 1617062400000, formattedValue: "3/30/2021"}
    length: 1
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    $a: false
    [[Prototype]]: W
1: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(1), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Calc-31 Days", …}
2: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(1), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Date Calc", …}
3: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(3), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Acct Lv4", …}
4: Q
  $1: "Acct Lv5"
  $2: "sqlproxy.09qavul18yvvi20zwnpkm1g9abpo"
  $3: null
  $4: "NONE"
  $5: "dimension"
  $6: "categorical"
  $7: w {$N: bl, $K: l, $J: S, $H: R, $M: Z, …}
  $9: (18) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  $a: false
5: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(31), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "ALv6", …}
6: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(80), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Frl", …}
7: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(4), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "BU", …}
8: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(2), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Fmponent", …}
9: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(1), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Country", …}
10: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(2), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Bu Lv2", …}
11: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(1), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Bu v3", …}
12: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(1), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Bu v4", …}
13: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(6), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Bu v3", …}
14: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(16), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Bu v4", …}
15: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(43), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Bu v5", …}
16: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(95), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Bu v6", …}
17: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(190), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Model Name", …}
18: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(1), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "treasury_side", …}
19: Q {$a: false, $9: Array(1), $7: w, $6: "categorical", $1: "Transaction Currency", …}
```

Comment: add example of how your data looks that's will be helpful i mean the array that you loop through images isn't helpful enough

Comment: hi @JS_INF ,  i have updated the question .